# Would switching on session.cookie_secure log out my users?

Tags: php, security, session-cookies

I'm running a https site and would like to turn on these in php.ini to improve security:

```
session.cookie_httponly = 1
session.cookie_secure = 1
```

I could find a lot of info about this on the web but not regarding the persistence of old session id's when switching this on.

Could switching this on result in automatically logged out users because php now expects secure cookies but logged in users don't have those.. just after switching?

Answer (score 5):

Anecdotally, I've switched this on for hundreds of websites in my career that were using HTTPS and never had it log everyone out.

These .ini settings are generally applied to new session cookies, and the `secure` flag is for browsers to know to not transmit over plaintext HTTP. It shouldn't have any retroactive consequences.

The code for `session_start()` invokes a C function called `php_session_start()` which (in most cases) [checks `$_COOKIE`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/83e495e0fdc0c59b449bd173d0c8df1999239634/ext/session/session.c#L1532-L1611).

The code for cookie processing is [SAPI-dependent](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/83e495e0fdc0c59b449bd173d0c8df1999239634/main/SAPI.c#L424), but does not contain any specific logic for "if `secure` was not set, discard it now that we expect it".

Barring some weird SAPI code that contains this logic, what's most likely happening is that cookies are no longer being sent to HTTP endpoints that lack HTTPS, so it seems like users are being logged out (but only if they're not using HTTPS everywhere).

In short:

- No, it *shouldn't* log users out unless they're not browsing via HTTPS (which they should be doing)
- However, if it *is* happening, the temporary inconvenience is worth the security gain.

Comment: Just to confirm, those flags are only used in the `Set-Cookie` header, which is sent to the browser. The header instructs the browser how to use the cookies in future (e.g. not available to JS, or insecure HTTP)... when it comes to sending the cookies back to the server, the browser only sends the name and value. The server has no idea what they were stored as, and if the server re-sends the cookies (with these flags), the browser will simply replace the old cookie... so setting these flags won’t cause the users to be logged out (unless there are other issues, like using HTTP)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will log them out, because their session will end.

Comment: Could you elaborate this a bit, or could you list a resource?

Comment: I had exact problem month ago. So I found out it on hard way :)